# How can I safely use an azure account name and account key in a cron job?

Tags: bash, azure, cron

I'm writing a bash script, it will be run as part of a cron job by a specific user made for the purpose. I have an azure account name and account key, I would rather not have the account key in the script. How is this normally handled?

Right now I'm leaning towards storing it as an environment variable for the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I went with a dedicated user for the job and stored the key as an environment variable for that user.